# sum according to field condition

Tags: sum, crystal-reports-xi

can you please help me with this on crystal reports.

|field1     | field2    |field3 |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
|code1      | abc       | 12.00 |
|code2      | xyz       | 11:00 |
|code3      | cde       | 12.00 |
|code4      | yabc      | 2.00  |
|code5      | xabc      | 2.00  |
|code6      | xxyzx     | 3.00  |
|code7      | fgfgf     | 43.00 |
code8 and so on....

i want to add all contains "abc", "xyz", and so on and if not just show the same name as above.

result should be something like:
|-----|------|
|ABC  | 16.00|
|XYZ  | 14.00|
|code3| 12.00|
|code7| 43.00|
code8 and so on...

note: included on the quotation will not be included in the required result

im still a newbie on crystal reports..

thank you in advance
grace

Answer (score 0):

Create an IF Then Else formula that returns the value if the condition is true and 0 otherwise.
Then, SUM that formula at whatever level of aggregation (Report-level or Group-level) you need.